# Suppose coin toss sequence

Tags: probability, algorithms

Suppose we flip a coin n-times. By a series of repetitions we mean successive tosses in which the same side of the coin lands (heads or tails each time). For example, in HHHTTHTH ( => 8) there are 5 repetition sequences.

> For example: HHH-TT-HTH -> HHH are 3 and TT are 2, summary there is 5 repetitions

What is the expected number of repetition sequences for n-flips ??

.

I tried to solve this after your advices, but I think I do something wrong

**Step 1**
We toss a symetric coin so chances for H or T are equal = 0.5

Let:
$ a_n $ - number of repetion sequences for n flips

In first toss we have:
$ a_1=1 $

For next tosses $ n+1 $ we have got 50% chances to continue sequence from $n$

As formula it's $ a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+1}{2} $

or 50% to beginn new series ofrepetitions:
$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}*1$

Let's write both together as recurent formula:
$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}*\left(a_n+1\right)+\frac{1}{2}*1$

After simplify:
$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$

**Try proof that**

Calculate this for n flips:

$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$

$a_n=\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$

$a_{n-1}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$

⋮

$a_2=\frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$

$a_1=1$

After substituting and calculating the above equations, we get the following:

$a_n=1+\frac{n-1}{2}\ = \frac{n+1}{2} $

And my question is  whether the above provisions are OK and how to proof this? Math iteration, induction? I don't know how to do this proof.

Comment: Your definition is not clear.  In your example, $H^3T^2HTH$ I would have said there were $5$ blocks because the sequence can be decomposed as $H^3+T^2+H+T+H$, but you make it appear that it is $5$  because $3+2=5$.  That is, you only focus on the $H^3$ and the $T^2$.  Can you clarify the definition?

Comment: Or are you asking for the number of entries $i\in \{1, \cdots, n-1\}$ such that $X_i=X_{i+1}$?  That one is also easy to compute by linearity.

Comment: Yes, as wrote in first message. I need to suppose sequence repetitions e.g. HHHTT = 3+2 = 5

Comment: So, how could $a_1$ be $1$?  For length $1$ there are no contiguous blocks of length greater than $1$.

Comment: it's first toss, initial flip i suppose, becouse next ones are $1/2$ chance for create next member of sequence or create new sequence

Comment: Sorry,  not following.  Either blocks of length 1 count or they don't. You seem to count them sometimes but not others.  Please edit your post for clarity.  Maybe work out the  values of $a_2,a_3,a_4$ explicitly

Comment: i always take 1 for $a_1$

Comment: Do this: list out all 16 sequence of 4 flips. Count the number of repetitions of each, then sum those counts and multiply by $\frac 1{16}$ - the probability of getting each sequence. That is the expected value for $n=4$. Now follow your $a_n$ scheme. Does it give the same result? If not, re-examine that "$a_1 = 1$" concept.

Comment: I did it and i have got a(2)=1, a(3)=1,75, a(4)=2,5.. can I suppose that sheme is a(n)=a(n-1) + 0,75 ??